# Making a copy of a key

Tags: halacha, gezel-stealing

Say that someone borrows a key, and, while it is in his possession, gets a copy made of it.

1. Has he violated any halachos?
2. Does it make a difference how public/private the room is?
3. Does it matter if the key is even used for a room, as opposed to, say, an alarm, elevator, or locker?
4. Is he able to use the copy?

Comment: Your last question send unrelated to the other questions. Regardless of whether one may copy a key, why on earth would I've be permitted to use the copy to do anything involving someone else's property? Regardless of how private anything is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the owner did not authorize that use of the key, the act of copying itself would then be an act of stealing akin to when a *shomer* (watchman) of a cow uses it to plow his own field (*shelichuth yad* - which is treated biblically as full theft).

Comment: I guess I didn't make myself clear. +1 for that much, but I was also wondering about using the copy.

Comment: Not disagreeing with your answer, but, the question states that he is BORROWING the key, not watching it. That means that he is using the key to gain entry to the places or electronic item (e.g. alarm, etc.) that the key is for. If he makes a copy of the key to use the copy for the same access, why does that matter? I can see a problem if at the end of the borrowed time he fails to return the copy. Then, he has gained unauthorized access or use. But why would making or using a copy during his borrowing time make any difference?

Comment: @DonielF Provided there is no *dina d'malchutha* otherwise, and that is recognized halachically, the second key would seem to be his, even if he formed it in a forbidden manner.  If that which it accesses is also within his rights to access, it doesn't seem that there would technically be a further limitation, without further rabbinic enactments otherwise.

Comment: @DanF The very act of copying requires manipulating the original key in a manner never authorized by its owner. That act should therefore constitute an act of theft according to biblical law.

Comment: @DanF This is akin to a *shomer* who is authorized to manipulate an object as necessary for its protection, but not for personal use.

Comment: @Loewian If he does it for his own use is he not Sholeiach Yad (BM 41)?

Comment: I'd like to see some link to source material as that would greatly help me understand the issue. When you borrow something, is there an inherent "authorized usage"? If I borrow your pen and I use the point to reset my modem, I'm "stealing"? I'm assuming in the case of the key, the owner has not expressly prohibited making copies.

Comment: @DanF Halacha recognizes default assumptions. My understanding of the OP was that the owner does not want a copy made. If resetting your modem is a reasonable use that there is no significant reason to assume the owner would disallow, that's entirely different. If, however, it's an unusual use that is e.g. likely to damage the pen, it would stand to reason that you would have to ask explicit permission first.

Comment: @DonielF If he is authorized by the owner to use it for his own use (i.e. a borrower-*shoel* or renter-*socher*), he would not be considered *sholeach yad* where he is using it in a way allowed by the owner.